# Delphi MSBuild Build Configurations From Command Line

Tags: delphi, msbuild, build-automation, delphi-2009, delphi-2007

Delphi 2009 uses **build configurations**. When you create a new project you have two default build configurations "Debug" and "Release".

Now I asked myself how to automate builds using MSBuild (which is supported by Delphi since version 2007).

You can start the "msbuild" command in the "RAD Studio Command Prompt" in some Delphi project directory and it will build the **default** build configuration (the last activated build configuration inside the Delphi IDE).

Now, I want to specify a certain (non-default) build configuration by a command line parameter.

The Delphi help asserts that the parameter is [/p:configuration=`<configuration name`>], which is **wrong** (Delphi 2009, Help Update 1)!

What is the right way?

Comment: Count me in for the suggested rework too.

Comment: I reworked this into a question and answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Now, if you want to change the build configuration you have to add the parameter
**/p:config=`<BUILD_CONFIG_NAME`>**

For example:

```
C:\Projects\TestDelphiApp001>msbuild /target:Build /p:config=Release
```

or

```
C:\Projects\TestDelphiApp001>msbuild /target:Build /p:config=Debug
```

---

*Copied from original "question"; note community wiki.*

Comment: You need to call `rsvars.bat` in your batch file first before this will work (at least in XE4, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17866719/2306907)).

Answer (score 10):

I tried this with Delphi XE.  It didn't work until I figured out I needed to set the environment variables referenced by the `.dproj` file:

```
SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0
SET BDSBIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin
SET BDSAPPDATABASEDIR=BDS
msbuild myproject.dproj /target:Build /p:config=Release
```

Comment: Yes, Delphi XE creates a RAD Studio Command Prompt item in the start menu.  That command prompt has the environment variables set.  But I'm not actually typing things into the command prompt window.  I'm running a batch file from my text editor, so the batch file needs to set up the environment.

Comment: If your delphi (2009+ at least) is installed correctly, just do 
call rsvars.bat
from your batch file and it will set the needed delphi build environment (that batch file is in the bin folder of delphi which is usually in the path in a regular installation)

Comment: Note that the rsvars.bat file from Delphi 2007 sets some environment variables wrong for Windows 64 bit. (Just in case somebody tries the above with this combination.)

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem and found the solution:

1. Write `/p:config` instead of `/p:configuration`
2. Write `"Release Build"` or `"Debug Build"` (in double quotes) instead of `Release` or `Debug`

It did it for me.