# How to change Delphi Build configuration?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2009

How to change the Delphi 2009 Build configuration?

The only place I see is on top of the Project Options window, anyway I don't feel that the options are applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Two Ways

From the Project Menu

1. *Project > Configuration Manager*
2. Select one or more projects from the *Applicable projects* list.
3. Select the configuration from the *Configuration* ComboBox.
4. Click the green play button (Makes the configuration active for the
   project(s) you selected)

From the Project Manager:

1. Click the + next to *Build Configurations* for the project
2. Double-click the configuration you want to be active.

In either case you need to rebuild the project for the configuration to be applied.

### Side note

You can also access build configurations from the command line:

[Delphi MSBuild Build Configurations From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558147/delphi-msbuild-build-configurations-from-command-line/558367#558367)

Comment: Perfect! Now I can do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: in RAD Studio XE it's moved to **View** > **Configuration Manager**