# EXE Size is too big in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, exe

I have created a simple project in Delphi XE2 with only 3 or 4 delphi forms which are only 8 or 9 KB in size. But If I see the exe size, its 12MB. I don't know how? What could be the reasons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975292/delphi-xe-disable-rtti

Comment: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2011/11/xe2-why-have-empty-vcl-projects-a-size-of-7-mb/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using the default Debug build configuration, which includes debug information in the exe.

You normally change the build configuration to release in order to produce a smaller exe for distribution, at the expense to lose the ability to debug it within the Delphi IDE (step by step).

Take a look at [How to change Delphi Build configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016643/how-to-change-delphi-build-configuration)

Using Delphi XE 3 with a simple form, the Debug exe is 10,995Kb whereas the Release exe is *only* 2,326Kb long. You may argue the latter is still big, but that's another question:

- [How to achieve smaller size of the executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150025/how-to-achieve-smaller-size-of-the-executable)
- [What Can I Do To Reduce My Executable's Size (Delphi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199476/what-can-i-do-to-reduce-my-executables-size-delphi)
- [Create smaller delphi-xe executables (delphi.about.com)](http://delphi.about.com/b/2011/07/26/create-smaller-delphi-xe-executables-remove-rtti-pack-exe.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Now I know, I was compiling exe in build mode. When I switched to release mode and then compiled, the size was in KBs.