# Build Project with XE4 and Batch

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I've been trying to make my own `.bat` file that helps me compiling/building my project.
In Delphi7 you could simply use `dcc32 MyProject.dpr` in a batch file and run it from anywhere without any problems. Since XE there are many changes such as Release/Debug and even Target Platforms. My Question is how can I make a simple batch file that builds my project (e.g.) in Target Platform X64 and a Release Build?

I've tried `dcc32 MyProject.dpr` but it says that `Vcl.Forms.dcu` was not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi uses the MSBuild framework now, so you need to call `msbuild.exe` instead of `dcc32.exe` directly.  That will allow you to specify build targets, platforms, etc as needed.  For example:

```
msbuild MyProject.dproj /t:Rebuild /p:Config=Release;Platform=Win64
```

There is a `rsvars.bat` batch script in the IDE's `\bin` folder that you need to call first to set up the MSBuild environment, if you are not using the **"RAD Studio Command Prompt"** link on your Start Menu to launch the console window.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it still can't find msbuild. `'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Any Ideas?

Comment: If you look at the properties of the `RAD Studio Command Prompt` shortcut, all it does is loads a new console window and auto-invokes the `rsvars.bat` script. I told you that script needed to be run in order to set up the MSBuild environment. If you do not use that shortcut to open the console window, then you **must** call `rsvars.bat` in your own .bat script.

Comment: @Benjamin: CALL the rsvars.bat file from your own batch file first; it sets up the environment to locate the proper Delphi path info and the path to locate MSBuild:  'CALL C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\Bin\rsvars.bat`, then on a later line `msbuild MyProject <options>`

Comment: It works now. I'm sorry for the missunderstanding. But it still doesn't build the x64 platform cause it says that Windows.dcu was not found. The X86 build works just fine. NVM. It's not configured yet.

Comment: That means your project's search paths and/or Unit Scope Names for the Win64 Platform are not configured correctly in the Project Options.